# Angular form submitting twice (ajax get request)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, angularjs

I have a controller that for some reason is submitting a form twice via a get request in AngularJs. I can see in my database that the form is being submitted twice, and also in the console network tab, it is logging the two submission, however, the first submission has the "Request Method" of OPTIONS, and the 2nd is GET. I think this may be a clue. I'm a bit confused, because i'm not passing in any 'options' into the get method, just the URL I am submitting to.

Html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div ng-controller="groupEditCtrl">
        <form class="span11" name="" novalidate ng-submit="createArtifact()">
            <legend>Create a new group</legend>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span5">
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input name="text" type="text" placeholder="Group Name" required ng-model="artifact.group_name" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="span5">
                    <p>
                        <small>What your artifact will look like:</small><br />
                        {{artifact.group_name}}
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <input name="token" type="hidden" required ng-model="window.token" />
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls controls-row">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn" value="Submit" title="Submit">
                        <span>Submit</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
'use strict';

function groupEditCtrl($scope, $http, $routeParams, $cookie) {

    $scope.createArtifact = function(){
        var requestURL = window.base_url + "/Group/CreateGroup?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&token=" + window.token + "&group_name=" + $scope.artifact.group_name;
        $http.get( requestURL ).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('You have successfully submitted a Cause/CreateCause');
            }).
            error(function(data,status,headers,config){
                console.log('You have FAILED submitting a Cause/CreateCause');
            });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was an issue with the custom api being built that I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 2):

A HTTP Options request is asking the server for the allowed methods that it can communicate with the server upon (amongst other things) so it's a normal thing to happen.

The Options request shouldn't change anything in your backend but it may well be logged as you're seeing. Double check that it isn't changing anything (and if it is then your backend may be configured wrong, and you should ask another question if it is!).

There's nothing wrong with your angular setup/use regarding the OPTIONS then GET.

Comment: @ryanwells, hmm, i was afraid of that. So you're saying that it's some kind of back end issue.

Comment: Should I be submitting the form in a different way? with a directive attached to the submit button perhaps? Is there a prevent default option that i'm missing here or something? I don't get it.

Comment: He is saying that it is not an issue. It just want to check that it the request type is available at the url you are requesting to.

Comment: @ZackArgyle Thanks, I realize that, but it's still submitting the form 2x.. I can add artifacts directly through a different web interface that we are building here, and it doesn't duplicate.

Comment: @flashpunk AngularJS doesn't submit the form twice; this HTTP OPTIONS request is something known as [Preflighted Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests), most likely used for CORS.

Answer (score 1):

For me headers: {'Content-Type': undefined} Work, And I don't see it call twice again.

```
$http.post("index.php", {id : $scope.A},{
    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}})
    .success(function (response) {
       $scope.OK = response.POLL;
    }
}
```